# Sessions on AppFog with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, session, express, appfog

I get a problem with sessions on my ExpressJS App. In local it works perfectly but when I host my App on AppFog I get some issues with the sessions, they are lost sometimes... In my admin panel.

I don't know why but, when the page is refreshed, the sessions no longer to work...

```
var restrictedArea = function(req, res, next) {
    if( req.session.access )
        next();
    else
        res.redirect('/signin');
}

// Get/Post example on admin panel
app.get('/posts/add', restrictedArea, admin.addPost);
app.post('/posts/add', restrictedArea, admin.savePost);
app.post('/posts/delete', restrictedArea, admin.deletePost);
app.get('/posts/edit/:id', restrictedArea, admin.editPost);
```

My app.configure:

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    //app.use(express.session({secret: 'some secret'}));
        app.use(express.cookieSession({
                secret: 'SECRET',
                cookie: { access: false }
            })
        );
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'some secret'}));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.render('404.jade', {
            title: "404 - Page Not Found",
            showFullNav: false,
            status: 404,
            url: req.url
        });
    });
});
```

My route:

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {
    if( req.body.username == user.username && req.body.password == user.password ){
        req.session.access = true;
        renderToAdminIndex(req, res);
    }else{
        req.session.access = false;
        renderToSignin(req, res, "Error, please try again!");
    }
}
```

signout function:

```
exports.signout = function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy(function(){
        res.redirect('/');
    });
}
```

Anthony

Comment: how do you initialize your session management?  what do you use? cookies? redis?

Comment: I updated my subject with my app.configure(); - I use cookies.

Comment: so req.session.access loses its value.  You should check the values in the cookie using the network inspector in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using express 3.x you need to use `express.cookieSession`:

```
app.configure(function () {

  ...

  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.cookieSession(
    { 
      secret: 'SECRET', 
      cookie: { maxAge: ... }
    }
  ));
```

reference: http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession

**UPDATE**

To wipeout the session:

```
exports.signout = function(req, res) {
  req.session = null;
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I need to set session in my route, not in my app.configure()... See my route above...

Comment: You need to configure express to place the session in the cookie, as in my answer, then you set the session values in your route.

Comment: I updated the subject, it works but i get an error for destroy a session. TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'destroy'.

Comment: And I added my "signout" function in the subject.

Comment: Wipe out the session variables with `req.session = null`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you it works. Do you think it's the best practice for destroying sessions? But, I hosted my App on AppFog and it works too. Thank you.

Comment: That depends. You may want to keep some data in the session like name of the user even when they are logged out. Otherwise clearing it out is fine.

Comment: what if you wanted to store the session in redis..and still it is not holding it..