# valum file uploader resets session in expressjs

Tags: express, appfog, valums-file-uploader

I am trying to upload an file using valum's ajax upload. On the server side I am using expressjs and it is a post verb. on the server side it sends back the req.session.id as json(sends the current sessionid). But at the end of the upload request, the session cookie is changed(the session is reset on the server/all the save variables are gone). I am not sure what is happening.
And this is happening with APPFOG not on the localhost.

```
app.post '/photo/upload', (req,res)->
  res.json {id: req.session.id}
```

on front end

```
            uploader = new qq.FileUploader
                        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader')
                        action: '/photo/upload'
                        allowedExtensions: [ "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif" ]
                        sizeLimit: 0
                        minSizeLimit: 0
                        onSubmit: (id, filename) ->  
                        onComplete: (id, filename, responseJSON) ->
                            photoId = responseJSON.id
```

It is plain expressjs app

```
Module dependencies.

express = require("express")
http = require("http")
path = require("path")
global.app = express()

app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 3000
app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
app.set "view engine", "jade"
app.use express.favicon()
app.use express.logger("dev")
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()
app.use express.cookieParser("your secret here")
app.use express.session()
app.use app.router
app.use require("stylus").middleware(__dirname + "/public")
app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))


app.use express.errorHandler()  if "development" is app.get("env")


routes = require("./routes")

http.createServer(app).listen app.get("port"), ->
  console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get("port")
```

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: @robertklep - I have put some code..

Comment: Can you post your middleware setup as well? Esp cookie/session configuration.

Comment: @robertklep there is no middleware/ cookie/session config..it is plain express app..I have add the app.coffee

Comment: Check out [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036322/sessions-on-appfog-with-expressjs), apparently AppFog doesn't work well with session cookies.

Comment: I think it might work. But I need to store it in redisStore on server side.